# Making a loop for lme() in r

Tags: r, loops, nlme

I am trying to use lme function from nlme package inside a for loop. I have tried (almost) everything now, but without any luck. Without the loop my lme function are working fine. I have 681 different lipids to analyse, so i need the loop.

Bonus info:

- I have used str() and my data has the same lengths before the loop

A simplified version of my data look like this:

`>dput(head("ex.lme(loop)"))
structure(list(Lacal.Patient.ID = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L), Time = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L), Remission = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Age = c(46L, 43L, 36L, 47L, 34L, 45L), SEX = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), BMI = c(25L, 26L, 23L, 27L, 26L, 27L), Sph = c(0.412, 1.713, 
    1.48, 0.735, 1.025, 1.275), S1P = c(2.412, 3.713, 3.48, 2.735, 
    3.025, 3.275), Cer..C16. = c(1.4472, 2.2278, 2.088, 1.641, 
    1.815, 1.965)), .Names = c("Lacal.Patient.ID", "Time", "Remission", "Age", 
"SEX", "BMI", "Sph", "S1P", "Cer..C16."), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")`

Here is what i do i R:

`library(nlme)
    attach(cer_data)
    Remission <- factor(Remission)
    Time <- factor(Time)
    SEX <- factor(SEX)`

## How I think the loop should look like:

```
lipid <-as.matrix(cer_data[,c(7:9)]) # my lipids a at row 7-9in my data 
beg <- 1
end <- nrow(lipid)
dim(lipid)
for (i in beg:end) { 
  print(paste("Running entity: ", colnames(lipid)[i], " which is ",i, " out of", end))
  variable <- as.numeric(lipid[i])
  lme_cer <- lme(variable ~ Remission + Time + Age + BMI + SEX, random = ~1|Lacal.Patient.ID, method = "REML", data = cer_data)
}
```

> Error : Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~variable + Remission + Time +  : variable lengths differ (found for 'Remission’)

## Without the loop my analysis are working fine (Lipid(x) is just one of the lipids) :

```
lme_cer <- lme(lipid(x) ~ Remission + Time + Age + BMI + SEX , random = ~1 | Lacal.Patient.ID, method = "REML", data = cer_data)
summary(lme_cer)
```

Can anyone see the problem with my loop? I am not used to programming or using R, so there is probably some stupid mistakes.

Comment: Now you do the lme for each row and it is wrong. Look at `end <- nrow(lipid)`. You should select unique lipids and do the loop for them.

Comment: and `dput` the data you use to make the question reproducible

Comment: You should re-evaluate what's in the rows and colums of your data set. Four observations: First, when creating your `lipid` data, you select a number of columns from the full data set. Second, for some reason you then write "my lipids are in row 1-881", which is surely not correct. Third, you create a loop runnin from `1` to `nrow(lipids)`, even though your variables are in the columns (and not in rows). Finally, within the loop, you select `lipid[i]` which selects neither a row nor a column but only a single element of that matrix.

Comment: If you have a solution, could you please post it as an answer rather than editing your question ??

Comment: `nlme` has some built in functions for fitting many models, which may work instead of for loop. see `?lmList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A blind answer, assuming that your dependent variables are organized in columns and not in rows (as I think they are).

The main difference between my approach and your approach is that I loop over the names of the lipids rather than their position in the data set. This allows me (a) to construct a temporary data set in a less error-prone way, and (b) to construct a temporary formula for the fixed-effects part of your model.

The `lme` function is then applied to the temporary data set with the temporary formula, and the result is saved in a list for easier access.

```
# names of lipids
lipid.names <- colnames(cer_data)[1:881]
no.lipids <- length(lipid.names)

# create a named list to hold the fitted models
fitlist <- as.list(1:no.lipids)
names(fitlist) <- lipid.names

# loop over lipid names
for(i in lipid.names){ 

  # print status
  print(paste("Running entity:", i, "which is", which(lipid.names==i), "out of", no.lipids))

  # create temporary data matrix and model formula
  tmp <- cer_data[, c(i,"Remission","Time","Age","BMI","SEX","Local.Patient.ID")]
  fml <- as.formula( paste( i, "~", paste(c("Remission","Time","Age","BMI","SEX"), collapse="+") ) )

  # assign fit to list by name
  fitlist[[i]] <- lme(fml, random=~1|Lacal.Patient.ID, method="REML", data=tmp)

}
```

In my opinion it's easiest to work with temporary objects that exactly contain what is needed at that iteration of the loop.

Note that I cannot check this solution for errors because you haven't supplied a reproducible example: [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

## Solution: My loop is working now with this simple code:

`lipid <-as.data.frame(cer_data[,c(7:9)])
dim(lipid)
for (i in 1:length(lipid)) { 
  variable <- lipid[,i]
  lme_cer <- lme(variable ~ factor(Remission) + Time + Age + BMI + SEX, random = ~1 | Lacal.Patient.ID, method = "REML", data = cer_data)
print(summary(lme_cer)$tTable)
}`

Thank you all for the amazing help!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, conceptually it should be sth like that

```
df <- data.frame(lipid = rep(c(LETTERS[1:4]), each = 4), x1 = c(rnorm(16, 10, 1)), x2 = c(rnorm(16, 20, 5) ))
    df

for (i in levels(df$lipid)){
  print(paste("MODEL", i, sep = ""))
  df1 = subset(df, lipid == i)
  model <- lm(x1~x2, data = df1 )
  print(summary(model)$coef)
}
```