# Summary report for each variable of a lme loop

Tags: r, loops, summary, nlme

I followed the suggestion about how [make a loop for lme()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889516/making-a-loop-for-lme-in-r).

With both the suggestion I made my lme loop for my 64 dependent variables.

My problem is the summary of the results. In the summary, the P Values are reported with scientific notation.  I tried to change the option with the code: `options(scipen = 999,digits=2)`, but the only results was that the p value now are reported with more than 9 decimal.

Here a sample of my data:

```
OCTA.Filtered <- structure(list(Cognome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor"), 
    Nome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor"), NumeroProgressivo = c(121L, 
    23L, 119L, 83L, 63L, 93L, 24L, 94L, 49L, 158L, 165L, 31L, 
    12L, 91L, 38L, 176L, 8L, 122L, 107L, 132L, 104L, 29L, 173L, 
    68L, 130L, 139L, 142L, 95L, 34L, 20L), IDpaziente = c(61L, 
    12L, 60L, 42L, 32L, 47L, 12L, 47L, 25L, 78L, 81L, 16L, 6L, 
    46L, 19L, 87L, 4L, 61L, 54L, 64L, 52L, 15L, 85L, 34L, 63L, 
    68L, 69L, 48L, 17L, 10L), Occhio = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("OD", 
    "OS"), class = "factor"), Età = c(26L, 64L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 
    39L, 64L, 39L, 32L, 26L, 74L, 37L, 81L, 61L, 36L, 71L, 71L, 
    26L, 34L, 39L, 31L, 38L, 62L, 36L, 54L, 34L, 47L, 45L, 33L, 
    69L), G6PDcarente = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Control", "G6PDH -"
    ), class = "factor"), Talassemia = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Ipertensione = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), Ipercolesterolemia = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), Diabete1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Diabete2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    PatologieOculari = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PMH = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), IRC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Terapiainatto = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), 
    BVCAlogMAR = c(-0.1, 0, -0.2, -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0, 0, -0.1, 
    -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0.3, 0, -0.2, 0, 0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 
    -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, 0), Equivalentesferico = c(0, 
    0, -1.63, 0, -0.25, 0, 0, 0, -4.5, 0, -0.5, -3.25, 0, 0.5, 
    -1.75, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, -1.25, 0, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, -2.75, 0, 
    0, -0.5), IOP = c(15L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    19L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 19L, 13L, 15L, 
    13L, 16L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 9L), FACHICO = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
    PSEUDOFACHICO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), PCO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), AFACHICO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), GLAUCOMA = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    GLAUCOMATERAPIA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "TRAVATAN"
    ), class = "factor"), AvgSSI = c(64.49, 64.37, 67.61, 66.32, 
    53.1, 78.35, 64.65, 80.85, 66.28, 70.25, 48.54, 54.49, 56.45, 
    63.7, 53.29, 55.65, 60.83, 73.56, 67.01, 72.06, 76.02, 63.25, 
    65.25, 56.82, 71.98, 77.3, 70.79, 65.31, 61.27, 68.98), L1DensityWholeImage = c(46.37, 
    48.69, 47.77, 46.98, 44.33, 53.33, 49.97, 51.45, 49.05, 52.28, 
    42.92, 45.68, 41.44, 49.94, 39.76, 41.67, 45.01, 50.81, 46.27, 
    49.49, 49.33, 51.46, 45.4, 37.67, 49.83, 46.74, 52.43, 51.2, 
    48.64, 47.37), L1WholeImageSHemi = c(46.41, 47.81, 47.96, 
    46.08, 45.86, 52.94, 48.65, 51.6, 48.44, 51.77, 44.41, 46.5, 
    39.99, 50.53, 40.2, 40.93, 44.2, 49.34, 46.09, 50.18, 50.05, 
    51.18, 46.4, 37.86, 49.25, 46.51, 50.49, 51.6, 47.38, 47.34
    ), L1WholeImageIHemi = c(46.34, 49.59, 47.58, 47.87, 42.79, 
    53.73, 51.3, 51.3, 49.74, 52.8, 41.49, 44.87, 42.85, 49.33, 
    39.27, 42.43, 45.93, 52.35, 46.47, 48.79, 48.53, 51.76, 44.38, 
    37.46, 50.42, 46.98, 54.31, 50.83, 49.98, 47.4), L1WholeETDRS = c(46.45, 
    49.2, 47.61, 46.79, 45.12, 53.25, 50.28, 51.22, 49.52, 52.94, 
    44.57, 45.28, 42.91, 49.87, 39.76, 41.77, 45.48, 50.71, 46.14, 
    49.81, 49.79, 51.39, 45.69, 37.55, 50.41, 46.38, 52.7, 51.61, 
    48.96, 47.82), L1Fovea = c(14.41, 15.55, 23.25, 29.9, 22, 
    27.08, 15.38, 23.62, 24.51, 17.83, 19.51, 9.87, 29.36, 21.11, 
    22.17, 24.91, 25.96, 15.81, 34.21, 19.34, 15.21, 31.16, 18.86, 
    12.7, 30.44, 22.77, 32.84, 17.55, 21.97, 28.96), L1ParaFovea = c(50, 
    52.48, 50.98, 45.62, 47.12, 56.48, 53.23, 53.81, 52.55, 56.46, 
    48.46, 47.66, 47.16, 52.59, 38.46, 44.91, 48.03, 52.91, 47.81, 
    53.07, 51.57, 51.95, 48.45, 36.25, 53.06, 47.55, 54.75, 55.52, 
    49.24, 51.98), L1ParaSHemi = c(50.4, 52.48, 53.59, 44.33, 
    46.74, 56.36, 51.5, 53.65, 52.63, 56.44, 48.28, 45.92, 46.05, 
    53.73, 37.16, 44.43, 47.96, 50.85, 47.46, 53.82, 52.39, 51.5, 
    49.9, 35.9, 53.27, 47.11, 53.63, 55.56, 50.77, 52.68), L1ParaIHemi = c(49.61, 
    52.49, 48.37, 46.9, 47.51, 56.61, 54.98, 53.96, 52.48, 56.48, 
    48.64, 49.41, 48.28, 51.45, 39.78, 45.4, 48.1, 54.99, 48.16, 
    52.31, 50.74, 52.39, 46.99, 36.6, 52.84, 47.98, 55.89, 55.49, 
    47.71, 51.26), L1ParaT = c(49.47, 52.6, 53, 43.6, 46.69, 
    56.53, 58.43, 55, 54.88, 53.21, 49.01, 50.11, 47.66, 51.86, 
    40.8, 44.9, 50.19, 53.56, 50.46, 53.27, 51.57, 55.33, 48.91, 
    39.01, 55.23, 49.12, 55.19, 55.74, 50.67, 51.59), L1ParaS = c(49.81, 
    53.32, 53.7, 44.31, 47.65, 56.46, 45.16, 52.74, 54.08, 58.17, 
    50.09, 41.2, 46.49, 54.59, 40.03, 45.92, 47.88, 51.29, 45.97, 
    54.08, 53.11, 47.68, 49.38, 36.54, 51.76, 46.86, 56.25, 56.43, 
    47.29, 52.72), L1ParaN = c(50.48, 49.92, 50.37, 44.05, 44.22, 
    56.14, 53.84, 53.85, 46.85, 57.09, 45.72, 49.83, 45.18, 52.85, 
    32.17, 43.46, 47.23, 52.6, 47.12, 53.92, 50.66, 50.21, 51.9, 
    33.01, 51.54, 47.34, 50.19, 54.93, 48.8, 51.56), L1ParaI = c(50.26, 
    54.07, 46.85, 50.52, 49.91, 56.81, 55.53, 53.65, 54.36, 57.39, 
    49.04, 49.5, 49.33, 51.07, 40.91, 45.37, 46.83, 54.21, 47.66, 
    51, 50.93, 54.53, 43.59, 36.46, 53.71, 46.85, 57.42, 54.99, 
    50.23, 52.03), L1PeriFovea = c(46.59, 49.48, 47.52, 47.77, 
    45.39, 53.26, 50.7, 51.48, 49.55, 53.21, 44.35, 45.9, 42.15, 
    50.14, 40.81, 41.46, 45.45, 51.35, 46.09, 49.97, 50.56, 51.98, 
    45.87, 38.87, 50.37, 46.91, 52.83, 51.72, 49.88, 47.29), 
    L1PeriSHemi = c(46.43, 48.92, 47.35, 47.03, 46.99, 52.4, 
    49.5, 51.64, 49.22, 52.93, 45.38, 47.3, 39.42, 51.31, 41.33, 
    40.72, 44.25, 49.53, 46.21, 50.77, 51.44, 51.63, 46.46, 39.26, 
    50.32, 46.11, 50.01, 52.12, 49.06, 47.76), L1PeriIHemi = c(46.76, 
    50.03, 47.69, 48.5, 43.8, 54.12, 51.91, 51.32, 49.89, 53.49, 
    43.33, 44.49, 44.88, 48.97, 40.29, 42.2, 46.69, 53.19, 45.97, 
    49.18, 49.65, 52.33, 45.28, 38.48, 50.42, 47.71, 55.66, 51.32, 
    50.72, 46.81), L1PeriT = c(41.95, 47.87, 45.93, 45, 42.47, 
    49.04, 47.53, 46.93, 46.98, 49.91, 42.91, 43.01, 39.26, 46.74, 
    38.6, 39.51, 42.04, 46.02, 42.32, 46.81, 49.17, 50.17, 44.12, 
    31.55, 48.22, 44.97, 47.36, 46.74, 45.35, 44.73), L1PeriS = c(45.42, 
    47.42, 47.15, 46.76, 47.83, 52, 47.28, 51.96, 47, 52.62, 
    45.33, 46.37, 36.18, 50.59, 40.05, 40.35, 44.27, 50.75, 45.8, 
    50.64, 50.82, 50.63, 45.41, 39.35, 49.38, 45.58, 50.06, 52.88, 
    48.55, 47.71), L1PeriN = c(51.12, 53.8, 49.62, 50.95, 48.73, 
    58.05, 56.06, 55.49, 54.88, 57.94, 49.25, 52.05, 49.63, 54.87, 
    44.83, 45.94, 50.03, 54.74, 50.26, 54.8, 54.57, 54.2, 50.53, 
    47.08, 53.01, 49.97, 58.1, 56.09, 53.53, 50.82), L1PeriI = c(47.89, 
    48.83, 47.39, 48.32, 42.55, 53.96, 51.89, 51.51, 49.32, 52.38, 
    39.9, 42.2, 43.57, 48.23, 39.73, 40.05, 45.55, 53.87, 45.97, 
    47.6, 47.57, 52.91, 43.45, 37.44, 50.89, 47.08, 55.76, 51.22, 
    52.1, 45.93), L1G11 = c(40.74, 39.58, 44.99, 39.66, 41.31, 
    47.39, 55.2, 57.75, 39.14, 44.91, 51.11, 39.88, 46.65, 43.04, 
    46.77, 33.91, 52.76, 53.98, 40.09, 54.47, 53.7, 45.42, 52.81, 
    47.57, 55, 43.21, 57.12, 44.68, 55.27, 54.13), L1G12 = c(46.12, 
    47.71, 47.88, 48.44, 47.91, 52.82, 48.92, 52.29, 46.4, 52.9, 
    45.81, 46.04, 37.75, 51.71, 41.03, 40.88, 45.69, 52.37, 46.11, 
    51.35, 51.12, 50.7, 45.93, 38.79, 48.4, 46.47, 52.03, 54.13, 
    47.87, 47.77), L1G13 = c(51.37, 53.94, 51.04, 51.65, 52.88, 
    58.12, 39.45, 45.35, 55.17, 57.43, 36.61, 53.94, 29.65, 55.22, 
    35.4, 47.18, 34.72, 44.66, 50.72, 45.71, 44.56, 56.18, 38.88, 
    31.78, 42.2, 51.15, 42.03, 56.46, 35.59, 39.59), L1G21 = c(44.15, 
    49.01, 46.67, 45.57, 42.64, 50.1, 57.14, 55.63, 50.01, 50.09, 
    48.84, 46.57, 48.08, 48.91, 41.85, 42.13, 47, 52.77, 43.85, 
    55.26, 53, 53.24, 49.72, 41.94, 51.49, 45.9, 56.31, 48.58, 
    53.01, 50.09), L1G22 = c(43.8, 44.73, 47.39, 43.7, 42.16, 
    51.49, 44.35, 48.99, 46.54, 49.92, 42.82, 41.09, 44.61, 47.85, 
    33.35, 41.12, 45.07, 46.3, 46.42, 46.9, 46.41, 46.54, 44.77, 
    30.57, 49.91, 44.17, 51.25, 49.15, 45.73, 48.3), L1G23 = c(50.27, 
    52.91, 50.14, 49.1, 45.25, 56.98, 51.24, 49.04, 55.03, 57.52, 
    44.26, 51.43, 42.59, 54.1, 39.32, 44.7, 43.45, 48, 51.1, 
    47.84, 49.77, 53.94, 45.18, 35.55, 50.54, 49.67, 51.04, 54.96, 
    47.75, 44.26), L1G31 = c(40.34, 45.94, 44.18, 45.2, 36.97, 
    47.36, 54.72, 55.89, 44.87, 47.96, 40.3, 37.12, 43.26, 42.07, 
    46.75, 36.68, 51.5, 56.9, 42.53, 53.3, 52.37, 45.4, 49.78, 
    48.86, 56, 41.2, 60.66, 45.1, 55.93, 51.4), L1G32 = c(49, 
    49.56, 47.1, 47.65, 43.51, 55.11, 52.37, 51.87, 49.83, 53.19, 
    45.7, 43.48, 44.11, 49.71, 40.67, 40.65, 45.19, 54.17, 45.05, 
    47.49, 47.76, 53.85, 41.66, 39.44, 50.77, 45.97, 56.05, 51.55, 
    51.29, 46.61), L1G33 = c(51.69, 54.94, 50.6, 51.96, 46.36, 
    60.71, 46.25, 46.15, 54.61, 56.69, 30.74, 51.66, 36.23, 56.93, 
    32.52, 47.94, 39.65, 48.09, 50.71, 42.93, 45.23, 57.97, 39.73, 
    24.25, 44.07, 53, 45.3, 56.32, 45.27, 44.06), L2DensityWholeImage = c(41.6, 
    47.27, 50.94, 51.68, 42.39, 55.27, 45.93, 59.71, 40.72, 55.48, 
    45.1, 38.14, 41.73, 47.45, 45.45, 38.19, 40.7, 53.06, 44.65, 
    49.69, 52.41, 45, 38.81, 46.6, 48.59, 56.49, 43.21, 54.91, 
    44.4, 41.53), L2WholeImageSHemi = c(42.33, 44.8, 51.31, 49.51, 
    44.78, 54.85, 42.94, 59.33, 39.12, 55.17, 47.1, 40.41, 39.35, 
    48.06, 46.15, 37.76, 39.57, 52.75, 43.84, 50.23, 52.44, 44.42, 
    38.94, 46.53, 48.16, 57.17, 40.73, 54.68, 43.49, 40.85), 
    L2WholeImageIHemi = c(40.91, 49.81, 50.58, 53.81, 40.01, 
    55.7, 48.94, 60.09, 42.53, 55.8, 43.15, 35.89, 44.04, 46.83, 
    44.7, 38.61, 41.96, 53.38, 45.53, 49.16, 52.39, 45.59, 38.68, 
    46.66, 49.04, 55.82, 45.61, 55.12, 45.37, 42.26), L2WholeETDRS = c(43.64, 
    48.92, 51.61, 53.28, 43.17, 57.69, 47.68, 60.74, 43.34, 57.04, 
    48.16, 39.96, 43.68, 50, 47.22, 40.33, 42.16, 53.85, 46.77, 
    51.77, 53.86, 46.49, 40.3, 49.56, 50.75, 57.06, 44.93, 56.6, 
    47.67, 43.33), L2Fovea = c(31.81, 29.84, 43.71, 45.96, 35.92, 
    44.14, 24.34, 44.28, 43.25, 36.92, 36.06, 28.96, 44.05, 35.95, 
    43.79, 42.54, 38.72, 34.81, 48.47, 38.4, 34.61, 43.17, 33.47, 
    34.24, 46.45, 42.68, 40.63, 29.07, 39.49, 47.33), L2ParaFovea = c(48.33, 
    50.64, 53.26, 54.4, 47.69, 58.42, 48.97, 61.1, 47.43, 57.24, 
    56.11, 46.55, 46.23, 52.25, 50, 45.34, 47.06, 54.69, 48.68, 
    54, 55.23, 49.69, 44.03, 58.47, 50.98, 56.74, 47.94, 57.67, 
    50.78, 45.24), L2ParaSHemi = c(49.46, 50.73, 54.46, 54.57, 
    47.26, 58.56, 47.45, 60.88, 47.76, 57.14, 54.92, 45.41, 44.83, 
    52.29, 48.77, 45.17, 47.11, 55.04, 47.62, 54.9, 54.4, 47.59, 
    44.23, 59.61, 52.11, 57.42, 48.17, 58.26, 51.79, 45.81), 
    L2ParaIHemi = c(47.19, 50.55, 52.06, 54.23, 48.12, 58.28, 
    50.5, 61.32, 47.11, 57.34, 57.31, 47.69, 47.63, 52.21, 51.24, 
    45.5, 47.02, 54.33, 49.74, 53.09, 56.07, 51.78, 43.82, 57.31, 
    49.84, 56.06, 47.7, 57.09, 49.77, 44.65), L2ParaT = c(51.19, 
    51.6, 55.37, 55.2, 50.22, 59.39, 52.4, 62.05, 51.62, 59.05, 
    55.71, 54.18, 49.63, 54.26, 54.48, 47.13, 50.73, 56.36, 50.51, 
    55.01, 57.44, 51.8, 46.65, 61.16, 51.41, 56.4, 48.9, 58.05, 
    55.5, 48.25), L2ParaS = c(47.95, 49.61, 52.65, 53.28, 42.78, 
    56.46, 41.1, 60.36, 44.91, 56.33, 54.46, 38.26, 42.05, 49.34, 
    50.16, 43.51, 44.05, 53.87, 45.54, 55.13, 51.66, 43.06, 42.09, 
    57.71, 51.5, 56.92, 47.05, 57.57, 48.38, 45.87), L2ParaN = c(49.07, 
    51.16, 55.75, 54.74, 49.81, 59.13, 54.12, 61.21, 49.17, 58.07, 
    58.69, 48.52, 45.92, 53.28, 43.54, 47.11, 49.14, 56, 49.82, 
    55.56, 57.32, 52.07, 47.43, 59.3, 51.49, 57.51, 49.3, 58.87, 
    52.71, 44.17), L2ParaI = c(45.08, 50.19, 49.27, 54.39, 47.95, 
    58.71, 48.24, 60.78, 44.02, 55.52, 55.57, 45.2, 47.33, 52.09, 
    51.89, 43.59, 44.34, 52.52, 48.85, 50.29, 54.5, 51.82, 39.94, 
    55.7, 49.51, 56.13, 46.5, 56.22, 46.56, 42.68), L2PeriFovea = c(42.68, 
    49.12, 51.42, 53.22, 42.1, 57.98, 48.17, 61.25, 42.11, 57.73, 
    46.25, 38.42, 42.91, 49.86, 46.52, 38.76, 40.82, 54.31, 46.13, 
    51.61, 54.18, 45.67, 39.44, 47.49, 50.84, 57.69, 44.19, 57.31, 
    47.05, 42.61), L2PeriSHemi = c(42.76, 47.47, 51.36, 51.85, 
    45.72, 57.52, 45.56, 61.07, 41.16, 57.67, 47.78, 41.26, 39.42, 
    51.42, 48.64, 38.78, 40.12, 53.93, 45.83, 52.74, 54.89, 45.16, 
    39.25, 48.29, 50.67, 58.1, 40.72, 56.89, 47.25, 41.95), L2PeriIHemi = c(42.61, 
    50.78, 51.48, 54.59, 38.49, 58.44, 50.78, 61.43, 43.08, 57.79, 
    44.73, 35.57, 46.41, 48.29, 44.34, 38.74, 41.53, 54.69, 46.44, 
    50.48, 53.44, 46.18, 39.63, 46.68, 51.01, 57.28, 47.67, 57.72, 
    46.85, 43.29), L2PeriT = c(46.84, 53.2, 53.58, 55.84, 50.13, 
    59.38, 51.72, 62.07, 48.08, 58.69, 54.14, 46.32, 47.07, 54.41, 
    50.85, 45.46, 44.98, 54.59, 48.39, 54.8, 56.17, 50.48, 45.24, 
    49.97, 53.13, 58.94, 47.08, 59.43, 50.12, 47.75), L2PeriS = c(42.96, 
    44.49, 50.92, 51.13, 47.37, 57.05, 43.39, 61.77, 39.93, 57.39, 
    46.24, 40.03, 37.91, 50.41, 47.37, 35.43, 39.57, 54.87, 46.61, 
    51.84, 54.96, 45.12, 37.41, 46.23, 49.97, 58.98, 38.95, 56.27, 
    45.07, 39.92), L2PeriN = c(38.64, 48.51, 49.42, 50.91, 38.22, 
    56.39, 47.32, 59.69, 37.8, 56.82, 44.97, 35.85, 39.22, 48.62, 
    46.52, 39.63, 38.65, 53.08, 43.63, 51.16, 52.39, 40.82, 38.71, 
    49.05, 49.07, 55.69, 42.7, 55.6, 45.27, 37.47), L2PeriI = c(42.27, 
    50.29, 51.74, 55.02, 32.66, 59.12, 50.27, 61.48, 42.74, 58.01, 
    39.7, 31.43, 47.4, 46.13, 41.17, 34.5, 40, 54.7, 45.9, 48.67, 
    53.13, 46.31, 36.41, 44.68, 51.18, 57.17, 48.05, 57.9, 47.77, 
    45.25), L2G11 = c(42.29, 42.78, 53.67, 49.45, 45.82, 54.92, 
    36.47, 55.33, 38.24, 53.29, 41.32, 36.03, 32.56, 46.65, 42.37, 
    35.01, 35.99, 50.45, 42.93, 44.99, 50.49, 46.07, 34.67, 41.64, 
    45.58, 56.53, 36.03, 57.15, 36.08, 31.44), L2G12 = c(43.26, 
    42.26, 49.79, 53.14, 45.61, 55.71, 43.12, 61.25, 37.09, 56.02, 
    46.61, 37.96, 39.55, 49.29, 46.33, 36.07, 40.38, 54.83, 44.53, 
    50.74, 53.75, 45.38, 36.86, 48.09, 49.1, 58.53, 38.22, 56.46, 
    44.74, 41.75), L2G13 = c(37.55, 40.84, 48.31, 40.22, 42.87, 
    48.23, 42.2, 60.35, 31.13, 53.38, 45.39, 40.24, 35.78, 41.49, 
    45.23, 30.65, 34.84, 51.71, 37.47, 50.29, 50.52, 39, 38.07, 
    38.21, 44.02, 56.04, 39.33, 47.78, 37.34, 40.8), L2G21 = c(47.27, 
    51.83, 54.12, 55.41, 49.3, 59.4, 48.88, 59.66, 49.32, 59.5, 
    49.73, 49.12, 42.56, 54.93, 43.6, 46.53, 41.11, 54.37, 49.61, 
    51.3, 54.68, 50.94, 42.16, 50.71, 49.31, 58.29, 44.67, 58.57, 
    48.2, 39.52), L2G22 = c(46.43, 48.89, 52.85, 52.96, 46.59, 
    56.36, 46.23, 59.87, 47.98, 54.25, 53.42, 46.8, 47.58, 51.04, 
    49.84, 45.8, 47.01, 51.63, 49.36, 54.03, 52.19, 49.39, 43.04, 
    56.75, 50.94, 55.5, 48.24, 52.67, 51.59, 47.93), L2G23 = c(42.9, 
    48.96, 50.96, 52.33, 40.84, 56.29, 51.26, 61.44, 39.05, 57.35, 
    56.08, 37.76, 50.14, 49.15, 50.44, 41.91, 45.75, 55.6, 47.32, 
    55.43, 56.21, 42.51, 47.34, 55.86, 54.83, 56.32, 49.04, 57.18, 
    51.48, 48.37), L2G31 = c(39.62, 52.79, 49.82, 53.31, 41.5, 
    56.54, 46.06, 57.42, 44.02, 58.75, 33.09, 31.62, 37.02, 44.45, 
    46.69, 38.14, 38.99, 49.75, 46.82, 44.58, 49.18, 45.56, 33.07, 
    47.45, 44.83, 54.74, 41.45, 56.72, 35.5, 36.14), L2G32 = c(40.12, 
    48.49, 50.99, 55.44, 33.85, 59.15, 48.91, 60.47, 41.05, 56.86, 
    45.15, 34.08, 46.45, 47.01, 43.64, 36.54, 40.81, 54.54, 45.42, 
    47.96, 53.02, 46.54, 33.9, 47.72, 51.26, 56.11, 48.38, 56.94, 
    46.15, 46.63), L2G33 = c(34.9, 48.63, 47.96, 52.95, 35.04, 
    50.81, 50.39, 61.61, 38.66, 49.9, 35.16, 29.6, 44.16, 43.09, 
    41, 33.09, 41.51, 54.67, 38.43, 48.01, 51.72, 39.54, 40.27, 
    33.01, 47.57, 56.35, 43.68, 50.68, 48.79, 41.43), FAZArea = c(0.325, 
    0.377, 0.208, 0.119, 0.207, 0.205, 0.427, 0.216, 0.189, 0.324, 
    0.222, 0.325, 0.128, 0.258, 0.157, 0.107, 0.209, 0.337, 0.126, 
    0.184, 0.33, 0.196, 0.297, 0.299, 0.176, 0.19, 0.225, 0.416, 
    0.175, 0.078), Perimeter = c(2.197, 2.367, 1.745, 1.358, 
    1.779, 1.732, 2.538, 1.803, 1.629, 2.218, 1.847, 2.229, 1.446, 
    1.971, 1.572, 1.328, 1.92, 2.241, 1.468, 1.618, 2.589, 1.741, 
    2.084, 2.075, 1.57, 1.656, 1.801, 2.534, 1.605, 1.114), AcircularityIndex = c(1.09, 
    1.09, 1.08, 1.11, 1.1, 1.08, 1.1, 1.09, 1.06, 1.1, 1.11, 
    1.1, 1.14, 1.09, 1.12, 1.15, 1.18, 1.09, 1.17, 1.06, 1.27, 
    1.11, 1.08, 1.07, 1.06, 1.07, 1.07, 1.11, 1.08, 1.12), FD300AreaDensity = c(51.61, 
    53.26, 56, 48.36, 43.61, 56.5, 49.89, 57.35, 50.68, 59.37, 
    46.52, 48.08, 53.71, 55.31, 45.29, 42.85, 53.49, 53.6, 54.7, 
    48.63, 53.96, 50.49, 49.5, 44.08, 54.07, 47.94, 56.87, 59.55, 
    47.01, 47.88), FD300LengthDensity = c(11.79, 12.81, 13.03, 
    11.34, 9.77, 14.4, 12.21, 15.23, 10.96, 13.97, 10.94, 10.8, 
    12.17, 12.72, 8.83, 9.65, 10.48, 12.59, 12.1, 12.8, 11.69, 
    12.29, 11.28, 8.03, 12.56, 11.74, 13.45, 15.06, 11.01, 11.54
    ), SNRARetina = c(0.76, 0.81, 0.97, 0.83, 0.68, 0.98, 0.84, 
    1, 0.82, 0.95, 0.68, 0.63, 0.74, 0.77, 0.58, 0.65, 0.73, 
    0.92, 0.83, 0.85, 0.91, 0.8, 0.85, 0.56, 0.94, 0.97, 0.89, 
    0.91, 0.78, 0.84), QIARetina = c(3.64, 3.69, 4.03, 3.65, 
    3.03, 4.39, 3.69, 4.43, 3.71, 4, 3.35, 3.27, 3.35, 3.75, 
    3.04, 3.16, 3.29, 4.15, 3.77, 3.92, 4.19, 3.52, 3.84, 2.79, 
    4.09, 3.96, 3.95, 3.96, 3.19, 4.17), OverallQIARetina = c(8L, 
    8L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 9L), 
    age = c(26L, 64L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 39L, 64L, 39L, 32L, 26L, 
    74L, 37L, 81L, 61L, 36L, 71L, 71L, 26L, 34L, 39L, 31L, 38L, 
    62L, 36L, 54L, 34L, 47L, 45L, 33L, 69L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"))
```

Here the code I am using to set the option to scientific notation off: `options(scipen = 999,digits=2)`

And here my code for the loop and summary:

```
flow.names <- colnames(OCTA.Filtered)[27:90]
    no.flow <- length(flow.names)
    fitlist <- as.list(1:no.flow)
    names(fitlist) <- flow.names
    for(i in flow.names){ 
      print(paste("Running entity:", i, "which is", which(flow.names==i), "out of", no.flow))
      tmp <- OCTA.Filtered[, c(i,"G6PDcarente","age","Ipercolesterolemia","Ipertensione", "IDpaziente","Occhio")]
      fml <- as.formula( paste( i, "~", paste(c("G6PDcarente","age","Ipercolesterolemia","Ipertensione","G6PDcarente:age", "G6PDcarente:Ipercolesterolemia","G6PDcarente:Ipertensione"), collapse="+") ) )
      fitlist[[i]] <- lme(fml, random=~1|IDpaziente/Occhio, method="REML", data=tmp)
      print(summary( fitlist[[i]])$tTable)
    }
```

Can someone help me to format p.value in the summary with 3 decimals? (e.g. p= 0.111 or 0.000) or, at least, to mark significant p value with a * ?

Thanks.

Comment: `fitlist` is a list, try something along the lines of `lapply(fitlist, summary)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik:  Thanks, Unfortunately, I am not so expert with R. I was trying to modify the code:     `print(summary(lme_cer)$tTable)` with     `> format.pval( summary(Model.macula)$tTable ,digits=5, eps = 0.00001, scientific = FALSE)` , but in this way I have only numbers, without the tTable. Moreover, I discovered that $tTable doesn't print the Dep_Var name. Is there a way to add a line with the var name for each repetition of the summary list? Thanks.

Comment: I figure out this solution: `options("scipen"=999, "digits"=2)` . Unfortunately, although I set `"digits" =2`  the pvalue is always with a lot of decimal....    ( `0.0000000000000000000000000000000007038031` ). Is there a way to fix this issue?? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, it will be easier to discuss the code.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: here a Link to an example dataset and my R.script file. Thanks. [link] https://www.dropbox.com/sh/78np8bs8iu6gu1h/AAC1GK6jNA2remrMFkKsqeM5a?dl=0 [link]

Comment: This is not the best practice, please see [here how to make a good reproducible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik. Sorry, I am just new on this forum. I just edit my question adding an example dataset and my R.script file. Thanks